# Convolution Theorem of Fourier Transform

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform

I'm interested in proving the "other way around" from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) which basically states:

$$\widehat{fg}(\xi)=(\hat{f}*\hat{g})(\xi)$$

Now I've tried some pretty basic things and got almost there, but I think there is a mistake or something I'm not allowed to do, since I don't get the final statement. I would appreciate someone looking through the following.

So basically on the one side we have with the definition of the FT:
$$\widehat{fg}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi}f(x)\cdot g(x)dx$$

On the other side I first insert the definition of the convolution:
$$(\hat{f}*\hat{g})(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\hat{f}(\zeta)\hat{g}(\xi-\zeta)d\zeta$$

Next I do the Fourier Transform of the two functions in the integral:
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}[\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \zeta}f(x)dx][\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-2\pi i x\cdot(\xi-\zeta)}g(x)dx]d\zeta$$

Then I combine the two integrals, since they are over the same variable and same space *(but this is not allowed, since $\int_A f(x)dx\int_A g(x)dx\neq\int_A f(x)g(x)dx$ so the error happens here)*:
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-2\pi i x\cdot(\zeta+\xi-\zeta)}f(x)g(x)dxd\zeta=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi}f(x)\cdot g(x)dxd\zeta$$

$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\widehat{fg}d\zeta=\widehat{fg}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}1d\zeta$$

But as you see the remaining integral over $d\zeta$ ruins everything. I would like to see where the mistake is and understand how the proof goes by using the inversion formula for the FT as it is suggested on wiki.

Comment: I think I found my error. I can't just combine the two integrals because they are on the same domain and over the same variable. $\int_A f(x)dx\int_A g(x)dx \neq \int_A f(x) g(x) dx$. But I'm still looking for the correct proof.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on: [Fourier Transform Proof $ \mathcal F(f(x)g(x))=(\frac{1}{2\pi})F(s)*G(s)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709352/fourier-transform-proof-mathcal-ffxgx-frac12-pifsgs?rq=1)

Translated to our notation, this would give:

Starting with the claim $\widehat{f(x)g(x)}=(\hat{f}*\hat{g})(\xi)$ and applying the FT inversion formula on both sides we obtain:
$$f(x)g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i x\cdot\xi}(\hat{f}*\hat{g})(\xi)d\xi$$
Now with the definition of the convolution we get:
$$f(x)g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i x\cdot\xi}\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\hat{f}(\zeta)\hat{g}(\xi-\zeta)d\zeta\bigg)d\xi$$
multiplying the RHS with $1=e^{2\pi i x\cdot \zeta}e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \zeta}$ we have:
$$f(x)g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i x\cdot\xi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\hat{f}(\zeta)\hat{g}(\xi-\zeta)e^{2\pi i x\cdot\zeta}e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \zeta}d\zeta d\xi$$
Because $|\phi(z)e^{az}|=|\phi(z)|$ we can use Fubini on the integrals above, which gives us:
$$f(x)g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i x\cdot\zeta}\hat{f}(\zeta)d\zeta\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i x\cdot(\xi-\zeta)}\hat{g}(\xi-\zeta)d\xi$$
from which we finally deduce the true statement:
$$f(x)g(x)=f(x)g(x)$$
hence our starting equation $\widehat{fg}=\hat{f}*\hat{g}$ is true and we are done.

Comment: Yes, you need the Fourier inversion theorem. Start with $f,g, \hat{f},\hat{g} $ continuous and integrable to make all this easier.

Comment: And the way you wrote your proof is weird. Start showing $\widehat{F \ast G}(\xi) = \hat{F}(\xi) \hat{G}(\xi)$ then use the Fourier inversion theorem to get $F \ast G(\xi) = \widehat{\hat{F}(\xi) \hat{G}(\xi)}$ and set $\hat{F} = f, \hat{G} = g$